# R: Use csv file as cbind format

Tags: r, csv, shiny

This concerns Shiny apps i have this code :
the data model is:

```html
2 3 4 4 2
6 2 3 1 0
4 1 1 0 4
3 2 2 3 5
2 3 5 4 0
1 2 2 2 1
5 5 0 3 4
```

```
>   #This function is repsonsible for loading in the selected file  
> filedata_DM <- reactive({
>     infile <- input$datafile
>     if (is.null(infile)) {
>       # User has not uploaded a file yet
>       return(NULL)
>     }
>     read.csv(infile$datapath,header=FALSE)   })
>      performanceMatrix <- cbind(
>     c(-120.0,-150.0,-100.0,-60,-30.0,-80,-45.0),
>     c(-284.0,-269.0,-413.0,-596,-1321.0,-734,-982.0),             
>     c(5.0,2.0,4.0,6,8.0,5,7.0),                   
>     c(3.5,4.5,5.5,8,7.5,4,8.5),       
>     c(18.0,24.0,17.0,20,16.0,21,13.0)   )




# results
  output$filetable_result <- renderPrint({
    Electre_tri(performanceMatrix,
                        alternatives,
                        profiles,
                        profiles_names,
                        criteria,
                        minmaxcriteria,
                        criteriaWeights,
                        IndifferenceThresholds,
                        PreferenceThresholds,
                        VetoThresholds,
                        lambda=NULL)

  })
```

I read csv file from input in shiny app like this `fileInput("file", "File"),

Now i want to use csv data (table) instead given numbers in cbind function !

Help is much appreciated. `

Comment: If you to access the data you read, I think just use `filedata_DM()` will do the trick?

Comment: thank you! but doesn't work ! the question is how can i transform csv file to the form presented in cbind function (using csv data as vector)

Comment: As we have no example of what the csv file would look like, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look to the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R shiny: read a table from file and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428626/r-shiny-read-a-table-from-file-and-use-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys! finally, it works by using this code:

```
  #This function is repsonsible for loading in the selected file
  filedata_DM <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath,header=TRUE)
  })


  # statistics
  output$filetable_result <- renderPrint({
    data2=filedata_DM()
    performanceMatrix <- cbind(
      c(data2$v1),
      c(data2$v2),              
      c(data2$v3),                  
      c(data2$v4),      
      c(data2$v5)
    )
    Electre_tri(performanceMatrix,
                        alternatives,
                        profiles,
                        profiles_names,
                        criteria,
                        minmaxcriteria,
                        criteriaWeights,
                        IndifferenceThresholds,
                        PreferenceThresholds,
                        VetoThresholds,
                        lambda=NULL)

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
     shiny::fileInput("datafile", 'Choose CSV File'),
      mainPanel(
         tableOutput("filetable_result")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  filedata_DM <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath,header=FALSE)   
  })

  output$filetable_result <- renderTable(filedata_DM())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You need to access the data you read with `filedata_DM()` because it's reactive. So, you shouldn't put that in a variable and use this variable as a data frame because `reactive()` returns an object that isn't a data frame.