# R Shiny: Read CSV and save in a variable with dplyr and ggplot

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add a fileInput into my R Shiny program that users can add their own CSV/Excel files into, however, I'm running into some issues.

If I run the code reading the CSV directly from my PC (no fileInput) I have no problem, but anytime I try to input it I get errors.

I've done some research and tried to copy what I've seen online, but their solutions are not working for me. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922126/reading-in-a-file-in-r-shiny) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428626/r-shiny-read-a-table-from-file-and-use-it) already, but their methods are not working for. Or I'm still doing something wrong.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  theme = 'custom.css',

  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = 'Student Grades'),
    dashboardSidebar(
      fileInput(inputId = 'file', label = 'Select a file...'),
      selectInput(inputId = 'periodVar', 
                  label = 'Select Period',
                  choices = unique(grades$Period)),
      uiOutput('secondSelection'),
      dataTableOutput('individualSummary'),
      img(src='lhimg.JPG', width = '100%')
                    ),

    dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          'Test',
          tableOutput('contents')
                ),
        tabPanel(
          'Graph',
          plotOutput('individualGraph')
                )
          )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # grades <- eventReactive(input$file, {
  #   read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  # })

  grades2 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    myTbl <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    return(myTbl)
  })

  # observe({
  #   grades2 = input$file
  #   if (is.null(file)) {
  #     return(NULL)
  #   }
  #   grades2 = read.csv(grades2$datapath)
  # })

  tidyGrades <- function(data){
    data %>% 
      gather(key = Type, value = Grade, (c('Test', 'Quiz', 'Homework')), na.rm = T) %>% 
      arrange(Period, Student,Date, Type) %>% 
      mutate(Weight = ifelse(Type == 'Homework', 30, 
                             ifelse(Type == 'Quiz', 20, 50)),
             Date = mdy(Date))
  }

  weightedMeanDf <- tidyGrades(grades2)
```

There is a small snippet of my code. I can post the entire thing if needed, but I don't want to make it difficult to read while trying to get help. The weightedMeanDf is just one thing I need to do, but I have a handful of other plots and tables that I need to generate as well. The commented codes are the different things I've tried based off solutions online. The closest I got was using the uncommented code (first reactive) function inside the server function.

But I get this error with it:

```
  Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive')"
```

I'm really at a loss and now I'm running out of ideas. Maybe I'm going about it entirely the wrong way. Maybe the best way is to use a reactive function for every plot and data frame created? I feel like that would just slow everything down as opposed to reading the csv file once, then generating graphs and plots based off the first reading?

Comment: Well, `grades2` is a reactive expression. It it not a data.frame. If you want to get the value of that reactive expression, you should use `grades2()`. But it's unclear exactly how you are using `weightedMeanDf`. Most likely that would be a reactive expression as well. `weightedMeanDf <- reactive({ tidyGrades(grades2()) })`

Comment: I'm finding that out. I'm actually able to now print out a datatable after importing the file. But my issue is using that with ggplot and dplyr. Is there a way to convert a renderTable object to a dataframe?

Comment: Well, you have to pass a data.frame to renderTable.  Just make that data source a reactive object then you can use the same object in renderTable and renderPlot or whatever else you like. It seems like maybe your question is not doing a good job of actually describing the problem you are facing.

Comment: You're probably right. I apologize for not being clear. But I think you answered my question with your first comment. I wasn't using grades2() and left off the parentheses. I still have a lot of work to figure out to change up my program, but I think I should be able to get it now. Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this???

```
library(shiny)
library(digest)

# Create data to read
write.csv(file="~/iris.csv",iris)

shinyApp(ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("path","Enter path: "),
        actionButton("readFile","Read File"),
        tags$hr()
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('contents')
      )))
),
server = shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  file <- reactiveValues(path=NULL,md5=NULL,rendered=FALSE)

  # Read file once button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$readFile,{
    if ( !file.exists(input$path) ){
      print("No such file")
      return(NULL)
    }
    tryCatch({
      read.csv(input$path)
      file$path <- input$path
      file$md5  <- digest(file$path,algo="md5",file=TRUE)
      file$rendered <- FALSE
    },
    error = function(e) print(paste0('Error: ',e)) )
  })

  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000,session)
    print('check')

    if (is.null(file$path)) return(NULL)

    f   <- read.csv(file$path)
    # Calculate ckeksum
    md5 <- digest(file$path,algo="md5",file=TRUE)

    # If no change in cheksum, do nothing
    if (file$md5 == md5 && file$rendered == TRUE) return(NULL)

    output$contents <- renderTable({

      print('render')
      file$rendered <- TRUE
      f
    })
  })

}))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great example!